# Fan control on HP Pavillion Desktop Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hp, fancontrol

I've been having some problems with my desktop overheating and shutting off.
I have a workaround for now using `thermald` and `intel_powerclamp` to limit CPU utilization to 70% and agressively throttle when the CPU temp sensor exceeds 60C (if it gets to 70C, the thermal shutdown kicks in and my PC shuts off, so I'm a bit suspect of the accuracy of the sensor).

I have a TG01-1183w HP Pavillion Desktop PC dualbooted with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04

In Windows, I am able to control the speed of the case fan, CPU fan, and GPU fan. However, in Ubuntu, I am only able to control the speed of the GPU fan (with [coolercontrol](https://gitlab.com/coolercontrol/coolercontrol)). Coolercontrol doesn't detect any of the motherboard fans.

I installed `lm-sensors` and ran `sensors-detect`:

```
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# System: HP HP Pavilion Gaming Desktop TG01-1xxx
# Board: HP 8767
# Kernel: 5.15.0-94-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400F CPU @ 2.90GHz (6/165/3)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): 
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8631
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): 
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): 
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:06a3 at 0000:00:1f.4.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at efa0 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Client found at address 0x4f
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  Success!
    (confidence 3, driver `lm75')
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP421'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP422'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP435'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP441'...                   No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Client found at address 0x52
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at 1:00.0 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 2 at 1:00.0 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 5 at 1:00.0 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 6 at 1:00.0 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 7 at 1:00.0 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 8 at 1:00.0 (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `lm75':
  * Bus `SMBus I801 adapter at efa0'
    Busdriver `i2c_i801', I2C address 0x4f
    Chip `Dallas Semiconductor DS75' (confidence: 3)

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
lm75
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

However, when I run `pwmconfig`, I get the following output:

```
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

I can see 5 "fan" devices when I run `cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device*/type`:

```
Fan
Processor
Processor
Processor
Processor
Processor
Processor
Processor
intel_powerclamp
TCC Offset
Fan
Fan
Fan
Fan
Processor
Processor
Processor
Processor
Processor
```

Here's the output of `acpi -c`:

```
Cooling 0: Fan 0 of 1
Cooling 1: SEN3 no state information available
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 4: B0D4 no state information available
Cooling 5: intel_powerclamp 51 of 50
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 8: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 9: Fan 0 of 1
Cooling 10: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 11: Fan 0 of 1
Cooling 12: INT3400 Thermal no state information available
Cooling 13: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 14: Fan 0 of 1
Cooling 15: pch_cometlake no state information available
Cooling 16: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 17: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 18: x86_pkg_temp no state information available
Cooling 19: TCC Offset 0 of 63
Cooling 20: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 21: Processor 0 of 0
Cooling 22: Fan 0 of 1
Cooling 23: SEN2 no state information available
Cooling 24: Processor 0 of 0
```

I tried adding the kernel parameter `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to grub and rebooting, but still didn't see any change.

I saw this post: [20.04 doesn't support Intel Core i5 10400?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346475/20-04-doesnt-support-intel-core-i5-10400) and thought maybe I need to update my kernel. I have a 22.04 live USB which I will try tomorrow to see if that works.

`lscpu` output:

```
CPU op-mode(s):                     32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                         Little Endian
Address sizes:                      39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                             12
On-line CPU(s) list:                0-11
Thread(s) per core:                 2
Core(s) per socket:                 6
Socket(s):                          1
NUMA node(s):                       1
Vendor ID:                          GenuineIntel
CPU family:                         6
Model:                              165
Model name:                         Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10400F CPU @ 2.90GHz
Stepping:                           3
CPU MHz:                            800.002
CPU max MHz:                        4300.0000
CPU min MHz:                        800.0000
BogoMIPS:                           5799.77
Virtualization:                     VT-x
L1d cache:                          192 KiB
L1i cache:                          192 KiB
L2 cache:                           1.5 MiB
L3 cache:                           12 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):                  0-11
Vulnerability Gather data sampling: Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:        KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
Vulnerability L1tf:                 Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:                  Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:             Not affected
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:      Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Retbleed:             Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS
Vulnerability Spec rstack overflow: Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass:    Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:           Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:           Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS SW sequence
Vulnerability Srbds:                Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:      Not affected
Flags:                              fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfm
                                    on pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe p
                                    opcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept 
                                    vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify h
                                    wp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux trilobyte 5.15.0-94-generic #104~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 16 13:34:09 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: `Found unknown chip with ID 0x8631` I saw a post suggesting it wasn't available until 5.15 but you have that, perhaps a newer kernel.

Comment: I tried my 22.04.3 iso (kernel version 6.2), but I still get the same `Found unknown chip with ID 0x8631`. I'll probably just make an adaptor that disconnects the PWM wire from the fan so that it runs at full speed all the time. I don't really care about the noise, I just want my computer to not shut off when I run heavy workloads.

Comment: what happens if you `modprobe it87 force_id=0x8628`

Comment: I ran that, and `lsmod` shows that `it87` is loaded. However the output of `sensors-detect` still gives me the same `Found unknown chip with ID 0x8631`. I tried also `force_id=0x8631`. I'm reading this now: https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/154, I might try some of the suggestions there.

Comment: `sensors-detect` updates `/etc/modules` which is the modules loaded at boot.  This solution bypasses `sensors-detect` and if it works you need to manually update `/etc/modules`. It's loading it87, does it show in `sensors`?

Comment: ahh okay got it. Yes, I can see the fan speeds now in `sensors`, and I can now detect the fans with `pwmconfig`. Hopefully I'm able to configure the fans now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

After the help from `rtaft`, I was able to get fan control working without changing my kernel version or upgrading distros.

The HP TG01-1xxx motherboard has a Super I/O chip from ITE electronics which requires the it87 kernel module.

I'm not sure if it was necessary, but I installed it like so:

```
git clone https://github.com/a1womg/it87
cd it87/
sudo make dkms
```

Then I added the following line to `/etc/modules`:

```
it87 force_id=0x8628
```

And removed all blacklists on `it87` (which I found in `/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist_*.conf`)

Now, when I reboot my computer, I am able to run sensors and get the following output:

```
pch_cometlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +47.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +28.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +25.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +27.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +25.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +28.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +26.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +26.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +28.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:        +27.8°C  

it8628-isa-0a20
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          36.00 mV (min =  +0.76 V, max =  +2.99 V)  ALARM
in1:           2.22 V  (min =  +2.27 V, max =  +2.99 V)  ALARM
in2:           2.23 V  (min =  +0.55 V, max =  +2.06 V)  ALARM
+3.3V:         4.01 V  (min =  +5.69 V, max =  +1.51 V)  ALARM
in4:           1.82 V  (min =  +3.02 V, max =  +1.09 V)  ALARM
in5:           2.23 V  (min =  +3.01 V, max =  +2.87 V)  ALARM
in6:           1.78 V  (min =  +1.21 V, max =  +1.82 V)
3VSB:          3.62 V  (min =  +1.34 V, max =  +2.23 V)  ALARM
Vbat:          3.38 V  
+3.3V:         3.62 V  
fan1:        2636 RPM  (min =   21 RPM)
fan2:        2076 RPM  (min =  183 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =   11 RPM)  ALARM
temp1:        +29.0°C  (low  =  -9.0°C, high = +119.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +32.0°C  (low  = -47.0°C, high = -14.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +30.0°C  (low  = -18.0°C, high = +47.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp4:        +28.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high =  -1.0°C)  ALARM
temp5:         +0.0°C  (low  = +61.0°C, high = -73.0°C)
temp6:        -49.0°C  (low  = +30.0°C, high = -24.0°C)
intrusion0:  ALARM

nvme-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +29.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +82.8°C)
                       (crit = +89.8°C)
```

The fans are running a little fast, since I just ran `pwmconfig` and hadn't started `fancontrol` yet.